# Error when attempting to disable Google Fit from in App

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit

Getting an `IllegalArgumentException` when attempting to disconnect from GoogleFit using `Fitness.ConfigApi.disableFit(mClient)` as described in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/disconnect). I'm able to connect and retrieve history data a-ok.

Error

> GoogleApiClient is not configured to use the API required for this
>   call.
>   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zzb(Unknown Source)

Disable/disconnection code (note i have checked `mClient.isConnected()` before calling this):

```
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = Fitness.ConfigApi.disableFit(mClient);
        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResolvingResultCallbacks<Status>(this, RC_DISCONECT_GOOGLE_FIT) {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull Status status) {
                updateStatus("Disconnected from Google Fit: " + status.getStatusMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnresolvableFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
                updateStatus("Error disconnecting from Google Fit: " + status.getStatusMessage());

            }
        });
```

GoogleApiClient config

```
 private void buildFitnessClient() {
        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE)).build();
}
```

Targeting API 23, running on API 21, using 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.0.1'

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when you build your `GoogleApiClient` you must add `.addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)` to use `Fitness.ConfigApi.disableFit(mClient)`. Which kinda makes sense just threw me as it was missing from the docs.

```
 mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE)).build();
```